# Update SharePoint list item through Caml Query(using the item title) - Not working - No errors either

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am trying to update my SharePoint list item based on the 'title' (not ID). I'm using Caml Query for the purpose. Below is the code, It isn't working. Please help.

```
    function updateTowerStatus(title, tower, status, comments)
{
    var targetSiteUrl = "https://office2.bt.com/sites/GBA-"+tower;
    var targetProductListName = tower+"Products";
    ClientContext = new SP.ClientContext(targetSiteUrl);
    var oList = ClientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(targetProductListName);

    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="Title"/><Value Type="Text">'+title+'</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>');   

    this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);   
    ClientContext.load(oList);
    ClientContext.load(collListItem);
    ClientContext.executeQueryAsync(onQuerySucceeded, onQueryFailed);
}
    function onQuerySucceeded() {   
    var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();
    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) 
    {   
        var item = listItemEnumerator.get_current(); 
        item.set_item(tower+'ApprovalStatusOpenreach', status);
        item.set_item(tower+'CommentsOpenreach', comments);    
        item.update();
        ClientContext.load(item);
        ClientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onUpdateSucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));

    }
}
    function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
       alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
    }
```

Any other alternate solutionsto do the job are also welcome.
Scenario is, I need to update status of one list when the item in other list with same title is approved/rejected. I can just save the ID and do it. But how will I store the ID of the item being created?

Comment: let me know if it worked?

Comment: I used api calls to do it.

Answer (score 1):

variable tower is not accessible in onQuerySucceeded() method. it is part of updateTowerStatus()